# Update all records with same field value whenever a record is updated

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I have a collection RawUnits. And all the records in it has a field saleInfo.group.id.
What I am doing is I am figuring out the recently updated record's group id. Then finding all the records with this same group id.

```
const doc = e.currentTarget;
const currentGroup = RawUnit.findOne({'_id':doc._id}).saleInfo.group.id;
const rawunitsOfCurrentGroup = RawUnit.find({'saleInfo.group.id':currentGroup}).fetch()
```

What i want to be able to do is whenever the current record's field which is followup is updated I want to update all the records with the same group id which I am getting in rawunitsOfCurrentGroup. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can update multiple matches with `multi` true:

> True to modify all matching documents; false to only modify one of the matching documents (the default).

```js
const query = { 'saleInfo.group.id':currentGroup }
const transform = { $set: { title: doc.title } } // title is just an example
const options = { multi: true }
RawUnit.update(query, transform, options)
```

See: https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update